# If statement inside a new Mailmessage body?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, if-statement

Quick question about `new MailMessage body` that I cant seem to find an answer to in google.

How can I make an if statement that checks if an element is visible and then takes the string in the element and applies it to the body?

```
mail.Body += "<b>" + D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "" + "</b> " + D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "" + "</br></br>";
```

Edit: Visual studio says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose in brackets, like:

```
mail.Body += "<b>" + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "") + "</b> " + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "") + "</br></br>";
```

This will evaluate your condition and return appropriate string as a result which will be concatenated.

If you miss out brackets, then it first tries to concatenate `D1ContactPanel.Visible` to "<b>" and then evaluate the condition which fails because it cannot evaluate the string. Hence the error "cannot convert string to boolean".

Comment: Good explanation :) I just thought today that you should think of it as maths, of course! *facepalm*

Comment: @Cammy :) It happens to all of us some time or the other!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some parentheses, not just in order to compile but also for the developer's eyesight :)

```
mail.Body += "<b>" + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "") + "</b> " + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "") + "</br></br>";
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, to think it was so easy.. Will be sure to remember to next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

```cs
mail.Body += "<b>" + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "") + "</b> " + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "") + "</br></br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Separate the string values from your boolean condition:

```
mail.Body += @"<b>" + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "") 
+ "</b> " + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "") 
+ "</br></br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, change your code 
from

```
mail.Body += "<b>" + D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "" + "</b> " + D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "" + "</br></br>";
```

to

```
mail.Body += "<b>" + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : "" )+ "</b> " + (D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : "") + "</br></br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Enclose in brackets like other answers to avoid exception, but I think you don't need to check two times and make this code more readable as below

```
if(D1ContactPanel.Visible)
   mail.Body += string.Format("<b>Subsidiary contacts: </b>{0}</br></br>", D1ContactDDL.Text);
```

then you can even move this string literals to constants or resources

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
mail.Body += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> {1}<br /><br />", D1ContactPanel.Visible ? "Subsidiary contacts: " : string.Empty, D1ContactPanel.Visible ? D1ContactDDL.Text : string.Empty);
```